# Android why the port 443 is opened?

Tags: android, https, port

I notice that my Android phone has the https port (443) opened.
This is the nmap report:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
443/tcp open  http    Mongoose httpd
|_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 400)
|_http-title: Index of /
```

The port is not accessible, if I try to access from browser to this page: `https://PHONE_IP` I get this error: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I tried to connect using adb shell and the port is actually opened, this is the netstat report:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:7777         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:7203         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:80           0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
```

But I can't understand which process bind the 433 port.
Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
Android netstat has no options, not even the -h option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recall if Android's `netstat` has the `-p` option but if it does, that would be the easiest way to learn the process id that has the port open.

Failing that, you can either walk through /proc/ directories looking at the file descriptors open by each process until you find the offending one.

Comment: there aren't options in android netstat

Comment: found! It was the Ad free web service